# Japanese Term for "Cutscene"?

Tags: english-to-japanese, terminology, video-games

As in, the kind you would see in a video game. Do people just use カットシーン, or is there some specific term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularly in film or video games, カットシーン is widely used.

Answer (score 7):

I often hear it referred to as [ムービー]{LHHH} (rather than [ムービー]{HLLL}), although I hear カットシーン is equally common.

Comment: 「デモシーン」とも言う・・・・